# figure of network

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to plot this figure and this is my code and result. I want the size of the blocks and their distance to be the same as the original figure. In addition "network" should be inside the dotted line

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\newlength\estilength
\settowidth\estilength{$estimator$}
\tikzset{
  block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em,text width=\estilength,align=center},
  tmp/.style  = {coordinate}, 
  sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
  input/.style = {coordinate},
  output/.style= {coordinate},
  pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}
  },
  point/.style = {draw, fill=black, circle, minimum size=0.8mm, node distance=1.5cm, inner sep=0pt},
  dashed node/.style={draw,dashed,inner sep=7.5pt,rounded corners},
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=15mm,>=latex']
    
 \node [block] (act) {$Actuator$};
 \node [block, right=2 of act ] (plant) {Plant};    
 
 \node [block, right= 2 of plant] (c) {$sensor$};
 
 \node [block, below=15mm of c] (delay) {$Delay$};
 
 \node [block, below=30mmof plant] (control) {$controller$};


\node [block, below=15mm of act] (me) {$measur$};

\draw [->] (act) --(plant);

 \draw [->] (plant) --  (c);
 
 \draw [->] (c) --  (delay);
 \draw [->] (delay) |-  (control);
 \draw [->] (control) -|  (me);
 \draw [->] (me) --  (act);
 
 \node [dashed node,fit=(me)(delay),label=above:{network}] {};
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To place "network" inside the node, just replace `\node [dashed node,fit=(me)(delay),label=above:{network}] {};` by `\node [dashed node,fit=(me)(delay)] {network};`. As for the distances, you can just use different dimensions to make the output the same as the picture you show.

Comment: You should not use math mode (`$...$`) to italicize text, since the kerning will be bad. Use `\textit` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

That label for *network* will be really in the center of the node, you should write it as label (see MWE below}.

In MWE I shortened nodes names, add `chains` library and in `\tikzset{...}`  consider only styles used in images:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                fit}

\begin{document}
\newlength\estilength
\settowidth\estilength{\emph{controller}}

\tikzset{
arr/.style = {-Latex, semithick},
every edge/.append style = {draw, arr},
FIT/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, densely dashed, inner sep=1em, 
                          label = {[font=\large]center:#1},
                          fit=#2,
                          },
  N/.style = {draw, fill=white, align=center, font=\itshape,
              minimum height=5ex, minimum width=\estilength,                
              text width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
              }, 
  P/.style = {N, font=\textrm\large, on chain},
            }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 10mm and 15mm,
  start chain = going right]           
    \begin{scope}[nodes={N, on chain, join=by arr}] 
\node  (act)   {Actuator};
\node (plant)  [P]         {Plant};
\node   (c)     {sensor};
    \end{scope}
\node (delay)   [N, below=of c]         {Delay};
\node (msr)     [N, below=of act]       {measure};
\node (cntrl)   [N, below = of msr.south -| plant] {controller};
%
\node [FIT= network/(msr)(delay)] {};
%
\draw[arr]  (msr)   edge (act)
            (c)  to  (delay);
\draw [arr]  (delay) |-  (cntrl);
\draw [arr]  (cntrl) -|  (msr);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Apparently I miss first image and demand that MWE  should reproduce it. New MWE below enables this:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                fit}

\begin{document}
\newlength\estilength
\settowidth\estilength{\emph{controller}}

\tikzset{
arr/.style = {-Latex, semithick},
every edge/.append style = {draw, arr},
FIT/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, densely dashed, inner sep=1em,
                          label = {[font=\large]center:#1},
                          fit=#2,
                          },
  N/.style = {draw, semithick,  align=center, font=\itshape,
              minimum height=5ex, minimum width=#1,
              text width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
              },
  N/.default = \estilength,
  P/.style = {N, font=\textrm\large, on chain},
            }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 10mm and 15mm,
  start chain = going right]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={N, on chain, join=by arr}]
\node  (act)        {Actuator};
\node   (plant) [P] {Plant};
\node   (c)         {sensor};
    \end{scope}
\node (delay)   [N=2*\estilength, below=of c]   {Actuation\\ Delay};   % here is adjusted width of node's shape
\node (msr)     [N=2*\estilength, below=of act] {Measurement\\ Delay}; % here is adjusted width of node's shape
\node (cntrl)   [N, below = of msr.south -| plant]  {controller};
%
\node [FIT= network/(msr)(delay)] {};
%
\draw[arr]  (msr)   edge (act)
            (c)  to  (delay);
\draw [arr]  (delay) |-  (cntrl);
\draw [arr]  (cntrl) -|  (msr);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want the size of the delay and measure blocks to be larger than the rest of the blocks, like the original figure

Comment: @zarko.I want the size of the delay and measure blocks to be larger than the rest of the blocks, like the original figure

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz.I want the size of the delay and measure blocks to be larger than the rest of the blocks, like the original figure. What should I do?

Comment: @Zarko.Thank you very much

Comment: @mzn, instead say "thank you" you should express your gratitude by up voting answer. Also, since it solve your problem, you may consider to accept them :-). Both with clicking on up-triangle and check mark at top left side of answer. As I sow, so far you not do at any received answer. Does no one of them not deserve this?